# Como puedo hacer la unión de 3 tablas(entradas, salidas, devoluciones) para mostrar un resumen de movimientos de un producto?

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de inventario con Laravel 5.
8.
Esto es lo que tengo en la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es una especie de tabla(en la vista) donde se reflejen todos los movimientos de un producto especifico(entradas, salidas y devoluciones) ordenado por fecha, acá un ejemplo de lo que pretendo hacer
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo las relaciones con los Modelos de la siguiente forma

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productos';

    // Inventario
    public function entradas(){
        return $this->hasMany(Entrada::class);
    }

    public function salidas(){
        return $this->hasMany(Salida::class);
    }
}

class Entrada extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'entradas';

    public function producto(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Producto::class);
    }
}

class Salida extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'salidas';

    public function producto(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Producto::class);
    }

    public function concepto(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Concepto::class);
    }
}

class Devolucion extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'devoluciones';

    public function producto(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Producto::class);
    }

    public function concepto(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Concepto::class);
    }
}
```

Quiero hacer UNION entre las tablas(entradas, salidas y devoluciones) pero no se como sacar el nombre de la tabla para diferenciar de donde proviene cada registro y saber si se trata de una entrada, salida o devolución para colocarlo en la columna Operación.

quizás deba crear una nueva tabla 'movimientos' en el esquema? que debería agregar o quitar?

Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Nos serviría mucho para ayudarte: conocer la estructura de las tablas y las columnas que deseas recuperar, si usas las relaciones de *Eloquent* o escribes todo directo con el *query builder*, etc., considera leer [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacer una consulta compuesta, algo parecido a esto:

```
    $query = DB::table('persons')
    ->join('companies', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('persons.company_id', '=', 'companies.id');
    })
    ->join('roles', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('persons.role_id', '=', 'roles.id');
    })
    ->join('cities', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('persons.city_id', '=', 'cities.id');
    })
    ->select('persons.first_name',
    'persons.last_name',
    'persons.gender',
    'cities.name AS city',
    'roles.name as role');
```